# Locally Indicable Hyperbolic Groups

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

It is unknown whether a [hyperbolic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_group) is [residually finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group).
Is it known under the additional hypothesis of locally indicability?
Namely: Is a locally indicable hyperbolic group, [residually finite]?

Locally indicable means that every finitely generated subgroup has a nontrivial group homomorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Mark Sapir or Denis Osin are probably the people to ask about this - and they frequent MathOverflow.  Why not post there? [And then link back to this question...

Answer (score 1):

[This was answered on mathoverflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88112/locally-indicable-hyperbolic-groups) The sort answer is that it seems to be an open problem.

Here is a reproduction of Mark Sapir's answer:

> The answer is "it is unknown". There are many potential counterexamples to the conjecture that all hyperbolic groups are residually finite. For example, let $\phi, \psi$ be two injective (but not surjective) emdomorphisms of the free group $F_2$. Consider the corresponding multiple ascending HNN extension of $F_2$, $G=\langle F_2,t,s| x^t=\phi(x), x^s=\psi(x), x\in F_2\rangle$. That group has a homomorphism onto the free group $\langle t,s\rangle$ whose kernel is locally free. So $G$ is locally indicable. It is an open problem whether $G$ is residually finite provided its presentation satisfies a small cancelation condition (see Problem 5.2  [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.2899.pdf) ).